# Why do we have to call func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) after calling addChild(UIViewController)?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

What exactly is a purpose of calling `func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?)`?

From apple documentation it says:

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the didMove(toParent:) method of the child view controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or, if there is no transition, immediately after calling the addChild(_:) method.
>
> The removeFromParent() method automatically calls the didMove(toParent:) method of the child view controller after it removes the child.

It seems like the function updates the transition of a viewcontroller, but I can't fully grasp the idea behind calling it. What would happen if I don't call it?

Comment: We do it in order to tell the child when we’re completely done with any animated transition as it’s added to the view hierarchy. Otherwise, it has no way of knowing that the animated transition (if any) is complete. Apple has always been very clear, though, that one “must” call this, even if no custom transition is involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't call it the child view controller won't be able to detect that it did move to the parent view controller. This may be important. Sometimes you need to do something in the child controller exactly after moving to the parent

Comment: Is this also possible in Xamarin?